# How to make sure a value isn't already in a Meteor collection?

Tags: meteor

Something like:

```
if (myCollection.find({'thingamaJig.$' : 'number1'}) = null) { 
"number1 is NOT in       myCollection" } 
else { "number1 is already in myCollection!"  }
```

?

Comment: There should be "`==`" in `if()` statement.

Comment: Try to do it .<pre>if(myCollection.find({'thingamaJig.$' : 'number1'}).count() == 0)</pre>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findOne`

```
if(!myCollection.findOne({thingamagig:number1})) {
    //Number1 not in collection
}
```

This will work even if thingamagic is an array e.g

a document looks like:

```
{thingamagig : [1,4,5,9]}
```

This would run because 10 isn't in the array

```
if(myCollection.findOne({thingamagig:10}) == null) {
     //Not in collection
}
```